# ERD a table got 2 FK from another table(one table)

Tags: database-design, erd

I am designing an ERD and I have got a question:

[image]

As you can see my "account" table has 2 FK relations in "order" table. So is it a good practice to do this? Or I have to separate my "account" table into "staff" and "client" tables?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) An ERD is an image of DDL.

Comment: What is your 1 specific question? What published DB design textbook/reference are you following? What method? What are its steps? Where is the 1st place you are stuck? Why/how are you stuck? You essentially ask us to (re)write a textbook for an unidentified method & bespoke tutorial with no details on what you misunderstand or do or don't understand. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs. [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [“help me"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097) [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097)

Comment: PS It is unhelpful & unclear to ask 'A or B' when A & B are not mutually exclusive and/or not the only options. (And you may think they are when they are not.) Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no restrictions on existence of multiple relations between entities. There are times that there exists multiple self referencing relations for an entity.
But in your specific domain, do staff and client share a same concept? Are they conceptually at some level of abstraction share same concept?

Maybe you could create an Account entity, and two more entities, StaffAccount and ClientAccount which are both has an IS-A relation to the Account entity.
Then when you are implementing the database and creating tables, you could decide weather create those three entities with one table or multiple tables.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes ...

You may have several relations between the same tables. This makes sense
**if the relations mean different things**.  Here, you'll probably have `staff_id` telling who in the staff is dealing with the order, whereas `customer_id` tells who has ordered and shall pay for and receive the order.

This may look odd with Crow's foot ERD notation, because they look redundant.  However this is not a fatality:

- it is perfectly possible to name the relationship, putting a name near the middle of the line, or even indicate the precise meaning for each side on the first and second half of the line (e.g. "ordered by"/"orders" vs "processed by"/"processes"). Some examples [here](https://www.relationaldbdesign.com/database-design/module7/idef1x-crowsfoot-chen-model.php).
- Chen's notation represent relations in an ERD with a large, named diamond, that tells clearly what the relationship means.

### But...

It seems that  `department_id` and `available` are only relevant for staff and not for customers.  On the other side,  for customers I'd also expect a shipping and a billing address.

If there would only be some very few fields which would be relevant only to customers or only to staff, it would be perfectly valid to let these fields be nullable and ensure that they are filled in a consistent manner.  This is called "single table inheritance" (treating two different kind of entities as one and the same).

However,  a customer is not a kind of account, and neither are staff.  So **you should not introduce inheritance ("IS-A" relationship)**.  Customers and staff HAVE an account.  It would therefore be strongly advisable to introduce two independent tables `STAFF` and `CUSTOMER`, and relate `order` to each of these tables. `Account` would  also refer to a `staff_id` and a `customer_id` (up to you to decide if both are mutually exclusive for an application account). this would increase separation of concerns.  which is far more future proof (e.g. corporate customers may allow several accounts for the same company)

*Not related:  never store a `password`.  Instead consider a `password_hash`:  this increases staff and customer security ;-)*

Comment: thanks, your answer is very helpful :), and also i know about hash password, i just forgot to add "hash" word :D